# Why does SegmentedControl in BB10 QML file only show 4 Options?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, momentics, segmentedcontrol

My SegmentedControl needs to have 6 options. So I have the following QML:

```
import bb.cascades 1.2

Container {
    topPadding: 20.0
    SegmentedControl {
        selectedIndex: 0
        Option {
            text: "1"
        }
        Option {
            text: "2"
        }
        Option {
            text: "5"
        }
        Option {
            text: "10"
        }
        Option {
            text: "20"
        }
        Option {
            text: "50"
        }
    }
}
```

In Momentics however, I see only the first 4 options. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in [documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__segmentedcontrol.html), right at the top it says

> SegmentedControl allows you to create a horizontal row with **up to four**
>   visible options.

So basically you can't. Unless you make a control that acts just like it

Comment: Try using a few ImageButtons, or Buttons. Maybe just Containers. You can't get exactly the same functionality, but might get close to it

Comment: Thanks @BojanKogoj, I'm trying Buttons enclosed by a Container each now.

Comment: Why would anybody think it's a good idea to make a design choice like this? Beats me.

Comment: @marko Indeed rather silly to allow only 4 segments max.

Comment: I don't think it's designed to have words inside rather than numbers, and they needs space